# samsung galaxy ace surfaceview/ camera error

Tags: android, android-camera

I am  writting an app that is supposed to be compatible with the samsung galaxy ace. 
I have the following code:

```
mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);           
mCamera = Camera.open();
```

It crashes at

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
```

And gives the following error:

```
/AndroidRuntime(18011): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have tried to set the value to 90, 180, 270 and 360, but nothing seems to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is because mCamera is null.

You should call `setDisplayOrientation()` after `Camera.open()`.

It is written in Android developer site (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

Comment: Did you configure permissions in AndroidManifest.xml? If you want to use camera, adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` is needed.

Comment: Are you using Nexus7? After Camera.open(), is mCamera null? What about using Camera.open(0) if your device API is more than 8?

Comment: I do have a nexus7, which i can use for testing as well. camera.open() is still null, same story with camera.open(0).